# How can i translate html text that in javascript using WPML

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpml

The issues are:
i want to translate words that are in javascript .i am using WPML plugin in wordpress. text within HTML tags are not showing in WPML strings

```
let html = `<div attrib class="applyOrCallLinkWrap byjs my-5">
            <div class="applyBtnWrap d-inline-block">
                <a href="/apply-now/" class="btn applyBtn orangeGrdBg thickRounded">
                    <span>**Apply Now**</span>
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="spratr d-inline-block">
                <span class="">**or**</>
            </div>
            <div class="callNowTxtWrap d-inline-block">
                **Call** <a href="${phoneLink}" class="header-phone-number-link header-phone-number">${phoneTxt}</a> **for instant approval** <sup>1</sup>
            </div>
        </div>`;
```

Comment: I recommend you have a look at [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) this allows you to create a localization object in WordPress

Comment: I have done that , But strings aren't show in  WPML--> String Translation .

Comment: ```$translation_array = array(
  'apply_now'     => __( 'Apply Now', 'mytheme' ),
 );
 wp_localize_script( 'maxcashtheme-script', 'object_name', $translation_array );```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you need to add all strings to the array and pass the array to your JS using wp_localize_script():

```
$translation_array = array(
    'apply_now' => __( 'Apply Now', 'mytheme' ),
);

wp_localize_script( 'maxcashtheme-script', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

Then in your JavaScript use the object and the key:

```
<span>${object_name.apply_now}</span>
```

Finally, you need to scan your theme in wp-admin *WPML > Theme and plugins localization > Strings in the themes*. After that the string should show up for translation in *WPML > String Translation*.